# Difference Between Ping on Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command-prompt, ping

I was messing around with the `ping` command on the terminal in Ubuntu, and I found something that confused me:

The Terminal makes an insane amount of send/receives, yet the Windows command prompt only sends a few packets and then exits. The only way I have been able to get a result is to use `Ctl+C` to stop the output on the Ubuntu Terminal.

What is going on here? I know that there is a large difference between the Windows command prompt and the terminal on Ubuntu, but I cannot figure out what that difference is. Is it possible that I am not using the correct syntax? (`ping example.com`)

Any ideas/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are two different programs,  that have different default behavior.  You can actually make one behave like another

On windows run:

```
 ping -t example.com
```

On linux

```
 ping -c 10  example.com
```

Look here for details

- [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)
- [Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ping.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 6):

Since Windows normally sends out 4 packets by default you can do:

```
ping -c 4 example.com
```

to achieve the same behavior as Windows on Ubuntu.  If you want it the other way around you could do

```
ping -t example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just a difference in implementation between platforms. If you want to limit the number of packets sent/received, Ubuntu ping has the -c flag that instructs the command to exit after a certain number of sends/receive requests.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/ping.8.html

Answer (score 1):

this is because the ping application on windows is different than linux. windows runs only a few to give you the information, whereas linux infinitely shows you the current ping.